# offline document for go/golang

Tags: linux, ubuntu, go, document

Is there any Ubuntu go offline document package that I can install so that I can read the package docs for Go offline?

I thought it would be `golang-doc` but it is actually not -- there aren't any Go package docs in it.

Then I research further and tried

```
godoc -http=:6060
```

but visiting http://127.0.0.1:6060/pkg/ gives me

`lstat /usr/lib/go/doc: no such file or directory`

How to read the Go package docs offline?

PS. My Ubuntu and golang-go package:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:        15.04
Codename:       vivid

$ apt-cache policy golang-go
golang-go:
  Installed: 2:1.4.2
  Candidate: 2:1.4.2
  Version table:
 *** 2:1.4.2 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/evarlast/golang1.4/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [Installing Go from source](https://golang.org/doc/install/source#tools):

> The source code for several Go tools (including [godoc](http://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc)) is kept in the [go.tools repository](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools). To install all of them, run the go get command:
>
> `$ go install golang.org/x/tools/cmd/...@latest`
>
> Or if you just want to install a specific command (godoc in this case):
>
> `$ go install golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc@latest`
>
> To install these tools, the go get command requires that [Git](https://golang.org/doc/install/source#git) be installed locally.
>
> You must also have a workspace (GOPATH) set up; see [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) for the details.
>
> Note: The go command will install the godoc binary to $GOROOT/bin (or $GOBIN) and the cover and vet binaries to $GOROOT/pkg/tool/$GOOS_$GOARCH. You can access the latter commands with "go tool cover" and "go tool vet".

Based on that information, have you tried:

1. Installing `godoc` using `$ go install golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc@latest`
2. Verifying Git is installed using `$ git --version`
3. Verifying the GOPATH using `$ echo $GOPATH`

Answer (score 21):

I am not sure the answer marked as correct is actually the correct answer - I could not access the golang documentation offline using that at least.

This works for me on a Mac. I have not tested it on Ubuntu.

If you have godoc installed, run the following command:

```
godoc -http=:6060
```

Then open a browser with the following URL: 
http://127.0.0.1:6060/pkg/

Or http://127.0.0.1:6060/ to see the first page of the golang web site.

All of the doco from the gloang web site will then be available to you.